# How can i change switchButton's value in smartface?

Tags: smartface.io

I am getting `true` or `false` value from database and I want to change the switchButton's sitation by looking this value.

I have a code as below but it doesn't work.

`x[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue` can be `True` or `False` and

```
if (x[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue) switchButton1.checked;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The switchButton's checked variable has to be defined in order to change it. Like: `switchButton.checked = true;`

Hope that helps! :)